# How to pass a multiline JSON string to ansible-playbook's --extra-vars

Tags: ansible

I am trying to pass a multiline JSON to the ansible-playbook's --extra-vars parameter, as follows

```
ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml --extra-vars <<EOF
{
    "param1": "value1",
    "param2": true,
    "param3": 9000
}
EOF
```

but I am getting the error:

```
ansible-playbook: error: argument -e/--extra-vars: expected one argument
```

Is there a way to pass the above multiline JSON string?

**UPDATE**

I agree with Setanta that if your json is long or complex outer double quotes and escaping the inner quotes will be more trouble then it's worth.

Therefore, I decided to pass two separate --extra-vars, one for string-only values and a second one for boolean and integer values, which requires the JSON format. The second --extra-vars is squashed into a single line:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml \
  --extra-vars "param1=value1 \
    param2=value2 \
    param3=value3 \
    paramN=valueN" \
  --extra-vars '{"boolean_param":true,"int_param":9080}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using outer double quotes and escaping the inner quotes.

```
ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml --extra-vars "{
    \"param1\": \"value1\",
    \"param2\": true,
    \"param3\": 9000
}"
```

A debug task returns:

```
- debug:
    var: param1, param2, param3


TASK [debug] *****************
ok: [localhost] => {
"param1, param2, param3": "('value1', True, 9000)"
}
```

If your json is long or complex this will be more trouble then it's worth though. Collapsing your json into a single line if it's short or reading from a file is usually more straightforward.

```
ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml --extra-vars '{"param1":"value1","param2":true,"param3":9000}'
ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml --extra-vars '@file.json'
```